# what to use instead of lineinfile to print duplicate values in a file via ansible, when running over multiple hostname

Tags: ansible

My playbook is running on multiple hosts, which have same value for Tanium client configuration settings.
I have used lineinfile module to print the value of each task in a file, which is skipping the already present value from the run on first host, while running on the second one.
I want to print the value , even if it is duplicate, in the file for all the inventory host name.
Below is the code:

```
- name: main execution
  hosts: dc
  become: true
  gather_facts: no
  serial: 1
  tasks:
       - name: fetch conf setting
         shell: /opt/Tanium/TaniumClient/TaniumClient config list | grep -i -e 'ListenPort' -e 
         'ServerName' -e 'ServerNameList' -e 'ServerPort'
         register: output2

       - lineinfile:
         line: "{{item}}"
         path: "{{playbook_dir}}/output.txt"
         with_items:
         - "{{ output2.stdout_lines }}"
         connection: local
```

After running the playbook, below is the status for **1st host**:

```
         TASK [fetch conf setting] 
***************************************************************************************
changed: [firsthost.com]

TASK [lineinfile] 
**********************************************************************************************
changed: [firsthost.com] => (item= The conf value for firsthost.com)
changed: [firsthost.com] => (item=  - LastGoodServerName: anenp.host.com)
changed: [firsthost.com] => (item=  - ListenPort: 17472)
changed: [firsthost.com] => (item=  - ServerName: anenp.host.com)
changed: [firsthost.com] => (item=  - ServerNameList: anenp.host.com,anenpc.host.com)
changed: [firsthost.com] => (item=  - ServerPort: 443)
```

**As mentioned above,all the values for 1st host get printed in the file.**

When, the playbook runs on **2nd host** it skips the common values, below is the status:

```
TASK [fetch conf setting] 
 *******************************************************************************************
changed: [secondhost.com]

TASK [lineinfile] 
****************************************************************************************
changed: [secondhost.com] => (item= The conf value for secondhost.com)
changed: [secondhost.com] => (item=  - LastGoodServerName: anen100.host.com)
**ok: [secondhost.com] => (item=  - ListenPort: 17472)**
changed: [secondhost.com] => (item=  - ServerName: anen100.host.com)
**ok: [secondhost.com] => (item=  - ServerNameList: 
anenp.host.com,anenpc.host.com)
ok: [secondhost.com] => (item=  - ServerPort: 443)**
```

How to print all the values, irrespective of duplicate values, in a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `blockinfile` a try:

```
- blockinfile:
    block: "{{ output2.stdout }}"
    path: "{{playbook_dir}}/output.txt"
    marker: ""
  connection: local
```